# Can class contain static object in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, static

Just curious.

Things like

```
ClassName * singleton
```

Here static in the sense that all members of the class share it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They sure can! Declare your static variables outside the implementation block in the .m file. I do this all the time when I create singletons.

```
--- MySingleton.h ---

@interface MySingleton : NSObject
...
@end


--- MySingleton.m ---

#include "MySingleton.h"

static MySingleton *sharedSingleton = nil

@implementation
...
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer that you already have - Yes you can.

You can have static variables that are visible to all objects of the class by putting them outside the implementation block.

You can have static variables that are only visible within a method for all objects of a class by declaring the static variable within a method. If you want to see an example of this, have a look at the boilerplate that is generated by Xcode for the table data source method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` At the top there is usually a declaration like:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
```

This is a static method, but it is only available within that method for other objects of that class. This gives you two things. Firstly - the slightly more efficient memory usage of having a single store for a constant item. Secondly - encapsulation is maintained by having a convenience variable only visible within the method that uses that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Eytan's answer: A good place to instantiate `sharedSingleton` is in the **class** initialize method. This gets called once before your class is sent it's first message (e.g. `alloc`) at runtime.

For example:

```
static MySingleton *sharedSingleton = nil;

@implementation YourClass

+(void) initialize // Note the plus sign!
{
    if (!sharedSingleton)
        shardSingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
}

// etc. 

@end
```